# How to have route Product/a23 instead of Product/Index/a23

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I try to serve the MVC request for our Products through the Index action of the ProductController.

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

And I want to avoid the pattern of "http://oursite.com/Product/Index/a23" (where a23 is the unique id of the product)

Instead I need "http://oursite.com/Product/a23"

My route.config is the default of the VS mvc web-app template, like that:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

What is the simplest, better way? I would rather not change the default mapRoute, as it works for other endpoints of our web-app, i.e. Order/Placement/18, Inventory/Stats etc. Any solution with adding a mapRoute or routing attributes would be most welcome.

Comment: I think it behaves as expected considering your route.config. Have you tried changing the 'url' field from "{controller}/{action}/{id}" to "{controller}/{id}"?

Comment: This would spoil my rest endpoints, which i want to keep like this, i.e. Order/Placement/18, Inventory/Stats etc

Comment: You could get around that using attribute routing on those, which seems to be the recommended way to go with REST endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ar